# How to parse Cloud SQL CSV export nulls ("N) with Pandas read_csv

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-sql

Using Airflow, we're exporting data from Google Cloud SQL to a CSV, and eventually loading that CSV into a different SQL warehouse. However, Cloud SQL exports null values as the string `"N` (This is a known Google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64579566). As an interim step, we need to open up the file and delete the `"N`.  There are also actual strings in the csv, using `"` normally.

Ideally, we'd be able to do this with pandas - we're setup to use a DataFrame for the next step.  However, I can't get read_csv to interpret the `"N` as nulls.  Here's the basic command I've tried:

`df = pd.read_csv(filepath, na_values='"N')`

I've also tried `na_values="\"N"`, but that gave me the same results.

It appears that `read_csv` checks for strings first, and for nulls second, so I'm getting output that looks like this:

```
Id                                                                           100
IncidentDate                                                 2018-08-29 07:00:00
StudentInvolved                                                      Psueudonym
IncidentLocation                                                       Classroom
IncidentCategory                                             Academic dishonesty
IncidentDescriptionDetails     [TESTING] How does this insert into table when...
FollowUp                                                                       0
ConsequenceGiven                                             Afterschool Academy
ConsequenceStartDate                                                         N,N
ConsequenceEndDate                                                           N,N
PrimaryViolation                                                 <email address>
Weapon                                                             <school_name>
CreatedBy                                                                    N,N
SiteName                                                                    1000
DisciplinaryActionAuthority                                                N,0,N
DocumentationUrl                                                             N,N
SIS_ID                                                                       N,N
SubmittedBy                                                                  N,N
Deleted                                                                      N,N
FollowUpNotes                                                                N,N
StudentLists_fk                                                              N,N
```

Any ideas on if `read_csv` is capable of parsing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately had to brute force it by replacing the text.

```
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as inputFile:
        raw_text = inputFile.read()

    edited_text = raw_text.replace('"N,', ',')
    edited_text = edited_text.replace(',"N\n', ',\n')

    with open(edited_filepath, 'w', newline='\n', encoding="utf-8") as outputFile:
        outputFile.write(edited_text)

    df = pd.read_csv(edited_filepath, names=incident_columns)
```

The one downside is that this will mess up any string that legitimately begins with the `N,` or `N\n`, but hopefully our users aren't in the habit of inputting stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace that value before loading into pandas dataframe. One way is to use `sed` command in linux.

`sed 's/"N/NULL/g' <filename>.csv`

then load into pandas

Automating the export statement:

```
folderName=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
fileName=`date +%H:%M:%S`
gs_path="gs://generic_test/$folderName/$fileName.csv"
gcloud sql export csv upc-asin-mapping $gs_path --query="select * from tableName;" --database=db_name
gsutil -m cp $gs_path .
sed -i "" 's/"N/NULL/g' $fileName.csv
gsutil -m cp $fileName.csv $gs_path
```

The above script will download the file, replace the `"N` with `NULL`and re-upload the same file with the same name. 
This is not a scalable approach.

Comment: This is roughly what we ended up doing, but inside of Python instead of Linux.

Comment: In linux, you have the option of using `-m` option in `gsutil` for multi-threaded download. I'm not sure if that exists in python. Hence, I prefer bash script